# How to handle validation message on post request

Tags: php, laravel, routes

a post request will be checked via validation Rules. If a validation error occurs the respond goes back to the post Route.

```
Route::post('invitation/result', 'UsernameController@result')->name('result.username');
```

And after this I get back an error no Message because in the view needs two parameter ($group, $parameter).

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">In welche Gruppe wollen sie den User {{$user->name}} einladen?</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{$error}}
                    </div>
                @endforeach

                    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.invitation')) !!} 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="iduser" value="{{ $user->id }} "/>
                            <select class="form-control" name="idgroup">
                                @foreach ($groups as $group)
                                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {{Form::submit('User einladen',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!} 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to give back the parameter which I have in the request for a validation like 'required'?

```
$request->validate([
        'idgroup' => [
            'required'
        ],
```

Thanks

EDIT: This is not validation 'required' but another one which I need in this context.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Invitation;
use App\Group;
use App\User;

class AlreadyInvitation implements Rule
{
    private $groupname;
    private $username;


    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $idgroup = request('idgroup');
        $alreadyinvitation = Invitation::where([['iduser', $value], ['idgroup', $idgroup], ['active', 1]])->select('active')->first();
        if(empty($alreadyinvitation)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->groupname = Group::where('id', $idgroup)->select('name')->first();
            $this->username = User::where('id', $value)->select('name')->first();
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function message()
    {

        return 'The User ' .$this->username->name. ' has an active request for Group ' .$this->groupname->name. ';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your understanding is wrong; how this should work is; GET -> fill out the form -> POST -> validate the thing and if all good return 20x otherwise return redirect which should point to the original GET page (with error message bag). For more clarity show the whole validation logic with redirection etc.

Comment: Please share your complete validation code from controller.

Comment: I have shared the validation code

Comment: I didn't understand what error are you facing or what are you trying to say?